# Java:Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity cognito user pool

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-cognito

I am using AWS Cogito service to fetch user credentials from Cognito using the AWS Java SDK.

I followed 
`https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/TxBVEDL5Z8JKAC/Use-Amazon-Cognito-in-your-website-for-simple-AWS-authentication` to write the code to authenticate users using the cognito user pools.

Prior to writing the code, i configured cognito user pool and named it demo with the following pool configuration fields.

```
Pool Id us-east-1_GUbY6qQ1v
Pool ARN arn:aws:cognito-idp:us-east-1:049428796662:userpool/us-east-1_GUbY6qQ1v
```

I used the above with the identity pool created to cater to the federated identity pool as can be seen in the attached picture.[Federated Identities User Pool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvvTj.png)

Now coming back to the code, i wrote the following function to retrieve the user identity and cache it so that if the same identity logs in, the call to the GetID() function is not repeated.

```
public UserIdentity getUserIdentity(User user) throws AuthorizationException {
if (user == null || user.getUsername() == null || user.getUsername().trim().equals("")) {
  throw new AuthorizationException("Invalid user");
}
AmazonCognitoIdentity identityClient = new AmazonCognitoIdentityClient(new AnonymousAWSCredentials());

GetIdRequest idRequest = new GetIdRequest();
idRequest.setAccountId(CognitoConfiguration.AWS_ACCOUNT_ID);
idRequest.setIdentityPoolId(CognitoConfiguration.IDENTITY_POOL_ID);

GetIdResult idResp = identityClient.getId(idRequest);

if (idResp == null) {
  throw new AuthorizationException("Empty GetOpenIdToken response");
}

GetOpenIdTokenRequest tokenRequest = new GetOpenIdTokenRequest();
tokenRequest.setIdentityId(idResp.getIdentityId());

GetOpenIdTokenResult tokenResp = identityClient.getOpenIdToken(tokenRequest);
UserIdentity identity = new UserIdentity();
identity.setIdentityId(idResp.getIdentityId());
identity.setOpenIdToken(tokenResp.getToken());
return identity;
```

}

The user class contains the field identity with the getOpenIdToken, this token is then retrieved, when asking for the credentials from cognito.

```
public AWSSessionCredentials getUserCredentials(User user) throws AuthorizationException {
if (user == null || user.getCognitoIdentityId() == null || user.getCognitoIdentityId().trim().equals("")) {
  throw new AuthorizationException("Invalid user");
}

AWSSecurityTokenService stsClient = new AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient(new AnonymousAWSCredentials());
AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityRequest stsReq = new AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityRequest();
stsReq.setRoleArn(user.getUserRole());
System.out.println("The received get open id token is: " + user.getIdentity().getOpenIdToken());
stsReq.setWebIdentityToken(user.getIdentity().getOpenIdToken());
stsReq.setRoleSessionName("FassetTestSession");

AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityResult stsResp = stsClient.assumeRoleWithWebIdentity(stsReq);
Credentials stsCredentials = stsResp.getCredentials();

// Create the session credentials object
AWSSessionCredentials sessionCredentials = new BasicSessionCredentials(
    stsCredentials.getAccessKeyId(),
    stsCredentials.getSecretAccessKey(),
    stsCredentials.getSessionToken()
);
// save the timeout for these credentials 
Date sessionCredentialsExpiration = stsCredentials.getExpiration();
return sessionCredentials;
```

}

The relevant part of the user class is below.

```
public class User {
  private UserIdentity identity;
  public String getCognitoIdentityId() {
    if (this.identity == null) {
      return null;
    }
    return this.identity.getIdentityId();
  }

  public void setCognitoIdentityId(String cognitoIdentityId) {
    if (this.identity == null) {
      this.identity = new UserIdentity();
    }
    this.identity.setIdentityId(cognitoIdentityId);
  }
```

}

The line AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityResult stsResp = stsClient.assumeRoleWithWebIdentity(stsReq), returns a ***403 forbidden*** error with the exact line below.

```
    2016-10-13 17:47:02,330 DEBUG [wire(wire:72)] http-outgoing-4 << "<ErrorResponse xmlns="https://sts.amazonaws.com/doc/2011-06-15/">[\n]"
2016-10-13 17:47:02,330 DEBUG [wire(wire:72)] http-outgoing-4 << "  <Error>[\n]"
2016-10-13 17:47:02,330 DEBUG [wire(wire:72)] http-outgoing-4 << "    <Type>Sender</Type>[\n]"
2016-10-13 17:47:02,330 DEBUG [wire(wire:72)] http-outgoing-4 << "    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>[\n]"
2016-10-13 17:47:02,330 DEBUG [wire(wire:72)] http-outgoing-4 << "    <Message>Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity</Message>[\n]"
2016-10-13 17:47:02,330 DEBUG [wire(wire:72)] http-outgoing-4 << "  </Error>[\n]"
2016-10-13 17:47:02,330 DEBUG [wire(wire:72)] http-outgoing-4 << "  <RequestId>fe4edd9f-913e-11e6-85cd-45155b40299e</RequestId>[\n]"
```

The trust permission for the user role is:

```
   {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Federated": "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": "us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        },
        "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
          "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": [
            "accounts.google.com",
            "graph.facebook.com",
            "authenticated"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

where **us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx** is the user identity pool id managing both the social as well as cognito user pools.

I have gone through numerous such blogs listing the trust permissions and cognito user pools to understand the above issue but in vain, i would really appreciate if someone could help me out in the above issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing the id token for your User Pools user in the logins map in your call to **GetId**.  You need to call setLogins on your **GetIdRequest** with a map containing **cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_your_user_pool_id** as the key and the **id token** of your user pools user as the value

Since you have not passed this logins map, the identity you get is an unauthenticated identity and you are only allowing authenticated users in your role policy.

See also: [GetId API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_GetId.html#API_GetId_RequestSyntax)